# What collection should I use for combining fastest key retrieval, but also fastest sorted enumeration in c#?

Tags: c#, performance, collections

Please can somebody recommend me some collection in c# (or maybe a hint how I can implement it myself) for storing key-value pairs, where I will always have at maximum let's say 50 of those key-value pairs. But usually there are only something like 5-20 key-value pairs. And I need absolutely fastest retrieval of a value for a given key. First I thought about Dictionary, because it has retrieval access time of O(1). But still I am not sure about the overhead of using dictionary for such small collections. But I guess Dictionary provides the best speed even for small collections like these?

Then I have another requirement, I need to be able to tell the next bigger key for a given key (For example I have keys with values 2,4,6,8,10,11,12,15 and when I say let's say 7, I need to be able to quickly tell, that the next bigger key than 7 is 8). So I thought about the collection of these keys to be sorted, then I would be able to quickly tell the next bigger key). I thought about using SortedDictionary then, but I found, it then have slower access speed O(log(n)), but would provide me this other benefit of finding next bigger key.

And by the way, through the whole use of this collection, it will never be modified, it just needs to be built at the beginning, which may be slow, it doesn't matter for me the speed of bulding it. Also I don't care for memory usage at all.

So for example, my solution could also as well combine Dictionary and let's say SortedList. It would be 2 collections combined just to maximize that retrieval speed and also that "getNextBiggerKey" speed.

Or now I am also thinking about just storing nextBiggerKey in a value of that key-value pair. So it would give me next bigger key at least for those keys already in collection.

So does anybody have some good ideas please, how to totally maximize the performance in this situation?

UPDATE: Keys I am talking about are actually of Fraction type. But with low values, neither numerator, nor denominator would ever be greater than 256, so bytes should (with high probability) be enough for both of them.

Thanks sooo much for any help, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You should just build a few versions and benchmark them all.

Comment: "And I need absolutely fastest retrieval of a value for a given key" - I suspect that's not *actually* the case. Are you willing to (say) spend 5 years modifying the JIT to tweak the *exact* machine-code generation for your use case, if it improves your performance by 0.001%? If not, you don't need "absolutely fastest" retrieval. You need "fast enough" retrieval for some requirement that you should determine and document.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I don't need fastest way in that meaning :D I won't play with JIT, just plain C# :D

Comment: What is the range of the values that will be used as keys? Is it a small range, or the full range of the `Int32` type?

Comment: Values are actually Fractions. But small fractions. To be exact, I am using all of these for MusicTime and MusicLength, which are measured in fractions. Like you have 1/8, 1/4 and so on notes. Now I have some bars with notes in it at some MusicTime. this collection should tell me at any given MusicTime (measured in Fraction) what notes should be played at that time. But also it should tell me, what notes will be played first after some time. 

And byte for numerator and for denominator should be probably enough. At maximum, I need short for both of them, but I don't think so :D

Comment: It's unrealistic to set "I need fastest in all situations goals". Set **actual** performance goals. Then measure the simplest solution that works. There is no point in *overoptimizing* on some metrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that the range of possible keys is small (a few thousands at most). In this case you could implement a solution based on a [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table). Let's say that the range of fractional keys is between 10 and 14, and includes halves and quarters. Also let's say that you have 4 keys in this range with the values 10, 10 3/4, 12 1/2 and 13. First you'll need a way to translate a key to an integer that will be used as an index in an array. In this case the translation function would be:

```
f(x) = (x - 10) * 4
```

So the key 10 is translated to the index 0, and the key 14 is translated to the index 16. Next you'll need to construct an array with length 17 (from 0 to 16). Below is a table showing the values of this array:

```
|   Key   | Translated |  Index  |  Value  |
|---------|------------|---------|---------|
| 10      | 0          | 0       | 0       |
| 10 1/4  | 1          | 1       | 3       |
| 10 1/2  | 2          | 2       | 3       |
| 10 3/4  | 3          | 3       | 3       |
| 11      | 4          | 4       | 10      |
| 11 1/4  | 5          | 5       | 10      |
| 11 1/2  | 6          | 6       | 10      |
| 11 3/4  | 7          | 7       | 10      |
| 12      | 8          | 8       | 10      |
| 12 1/4  | 9          | 9       | 10      |
| 12 1/2  | 10         | 10      | 10      |
| 12 3/4  | 11         | 11      | 12      |
| 13      | 12         | 12      | 12      |
| 13 1/4  | 13         | 13      | -1      |
| 13 1/2  | 14         | 14      | -1      |
| 13 3/4  | 15         | 15      | -1      |
| 14      | 16         | 16      | -1      |
```

No let's use this array to make some searches.

1. Does the key 12 exist? We apply the translation function `(12 - 10) * 4` and we get the index 8. The value of the `array[8]` is 10. 10 is different from
   8, so the key 12 does not exist.
2. What is the next bigger key of the key 10 3/4? We apply the translation function and we get the index 3. The `array[3]` is 3, so the key exists, but we are not interested in that. We need to look at the next array element, the `array[4]`. This has the value 10, which is a translation of the key 12 1/4. So the next bigger key of 10 3/4 is 12 1/4.

Now that you have a way to search this structure by key, you can think about how to associate each key with a value, to end up with a proper dictionary. The simplest way could be to add another array in the mix, with equal length, storing the value of each key in the same index.

Comment: An implementation of this idea can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/theodorzoulias/3041744f55a325c030cfa55f1f46240d).

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

If the key is actually an integer as you showed, there is no advantage of calculating a hash to search for an element (so no need for a collection which hashes the key). Since you can build the list once and then can work with an immutable list, I think a binary search is the fastest you can get.

What I would try first is a normal `List<T>` of KeyValue pairs, fill it with items, sort it once and then use [List.BinarySearch()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-6.0) to search for the elements. To be sure you should benchmark multiple scenarios, but this is surely a good start.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Well, my keys are actually not integers, but fractions. And can it possibly be faster to do binary search with O(log(n)) speed, as opposed to counting hash function? I am still not really sure about overhead of counting hash function opposed to let's say that binary search you mentioned, when having collection of no more then 50 key-value pairs.
And yeah, I should probably still try to implement it in many different ways and benchmark them all, to be really sure what is the fastest way for me :)
But still, thanks again for your reply bro :)

Comment: @Petrz147 - Calculating the hash of the key allows to do the key-comparison very fast (just integers), and only if a match was found, it has to do the exact comparison. If the keys are already integers there is no difference (the hash of an int is the int itself). For keys of different types you have to measure it. Make sure you compile in the `release` mode for doing benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies :) And yeah, I will update question, that keys are fractions.